# Cant Fetch Data From MYSQL While Sending Email With PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am sending email to my subscribers and all email adresses are inserted in table of MYSQl. But with it i want to send some articles which are located in other table of same database. Please help me. In "$name" Its fetching only 1 row (I want to fetch up all data with id given there).

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['send'])){
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username ";
$password = "password ";
$dbname = "db";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 where id in (1, 3, 2, 4)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$name = $row["title"];

}}else {}
$conn->close();
}
?>

<?php if(isset($_POST['send'])){
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT email, subid FROM table2";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

$subid = $row["subid"];

$email_to = $row["email"];
$subject = "Newsletter | OnlineDealsIndia";
$header = "From: OnlineDealsIndia <noreply@onlinedealsindia.in>\r\n"; 
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$header.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
$header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 

$message = '<h3>Todays Top Deals!</h3><hr>

<li>' .$name. '</li>

<a href="http://www.onlinedealsindia.in/newsletter/unsubscribe/?subid=' .$subid. '">Click Here</a> To Unsubscribe
';
mail($email_to,$subject,$message,$header);
}}else {}

$conn->close();
}
?>
```

In "$name" its should fetch all rows for which i provided id above.

All answer will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In one loop you're fetching `$name` and then setting it over and over again to the same place. Didn't you want to add that to an array?

Comment: It cant be that "$name" should fetch all 4 rows and show.

Comment: `$name = $value`  won't magically accumulate a list. `$name[] = $value` will add to an array.

Comment: You can either store name in an array, or you can just use your mail function inside the `while($row=$rs->fetch_assoc())` loop

Comment: Can u pls edit in coding and send

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php if ( isset( $_POST['send'] ) ) {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username   = "username ";
    $password   = "password ";
    $dbname     = "db";

    $conn = new mysqli( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );
    if ( $conn->connect_error ) {
        die( "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error );
    }

    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM table1 where id in (1, 3, 2, 4)";
    $result = $conn->query( $sql );

    $subject = "Newsletter | OnlineDealsIndia";
    $header  = "From: OnlineDealsIndia <noreply@onlinedealsindia.in>\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $header .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";

    $message = '<h3>Todays Top Deals!</h3><hr><ul>';
    if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            $message .= '<li>' . $row["title"] . '</li>';
        }
    }
    $message .= '</ul><a href="http://www.onlinedealsindia.in/newsletter/unsubscribe/?subid=' . $subid . '">Click Here</a> To Unsubscribe';

    $sql    = "SELECT email, subid FROM table2";
    $result = $conn->query( $sql );

    if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            $subid    = $row["subid"];
            $email_to = $row["email"];
            mail( $email_to, $subject, $message, $header );
        }
    }

    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: Opening and closing and then opening all over again does seem pointless.

Comment: There is a lot more space to improve this code, I did as little as possible changes to make it work to show how fix this particular issue from question.

Comment: Yeah, not faulting you really, just making an observation.

Comment: And what is the reason? Error or it's not showing all titles?

Comment: Well i am new to php, so if u guys pls check and give me proper coding (It will more great full) than you

Comment: I've fixed formatting and simplify the code, looks like it should work. I can't test it without database. You sure that you have everything in DB?

Comment: It's array of "1 things", did you try to run this code?

Comment: For Ex. 1) foreach($name as $item 2) foreach($description as $des and than i put - ' .$item. ' ; ' .$des. '